# How to use fixtures in Jasmine.js version 2.0.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Fixtures are working fine for my test suites in jasmine.js version 1.3.1. **After upgrading Jasmine.js version to 2.0.0, fixtures are not working.**

Can anyone explain, how to make my code workable for fixtures in jasmine.js version 2.0.0?

I have checked this jasmine v2.0.0 release notes, but nothing releated to fixtures: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/v2.0.0/release_notes/20.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below complete script is working fine for me to load the fixtures to test your html snippets.

I have referred this url  and this url helped me  to load the fixtures:http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/js-ref/testing-dom-events-using-jquery-and-jasmine-2.0.html

And You have to **check some of the Jasmine.js framework syntax as well in jasmine.js v2.0.0**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Jasmine v2.0 DOM Tests Spec Runner</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-core/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     var MSG = "Hello World!";

     function hideMessage() {
       $( "#pMsg" ).html("");
     }

     function showMessage() {
       $( "#pMsg" ).html(MSG); 
     }

     function setUpHTMLFixture() {
       setFixtures('<form id="testForm" action="">'
                  +'  <h1>Test Form</h1>'
                  +'  <input type="text" id="txtMessage">'
                  +'  <br>'
                  +'  <button id="btnHideMessage" type="button" onclick="hideMessage()">Hide Message</button>'
                  +'  <button id="btnShowMessage" type="button" onclick="showMessage()">Show Message</button>'
                  +'  <br>'
                  +'  <p id="pMsg"></p>'
                  +'</form>');

    }

describe("DOM TESTS:***************", function() { 
  describe("Button Click Event Tests", function() {
    var spyEvent;

    beforeEach(function() {
      setUpHTMLFixture();
    });

    it ("should invoke the btnShowMessage click event.", function() {
      spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#btnShowMessage', 'click');
      $('#btnShowMessage').trigger( "click" );

      expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#btnShowMessage');
      expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
    });

    it ("should invoke the btnHideMessage click event.", function() {
      spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#btnHideMessage', 'click');
      $('#btnHideMessage').trigger( "click" );

      expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#btnHideMessage');
      expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
    });
  });

  describe("Show message tests", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      setUpHTMLFixture();
      $('#txtMessage').val(MSG);
      $('#btnShowMessage').trigger( "click" );
    });

    it ("should display the message when button is clicked.", function() {
      expect($('#pMsg')).toHaveText($('#txtMessage').val());
    });
  });

  describe("Hide message tests", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      setUpHTMLFixture();
      $('#pMsg').text(MSG);
      $('#btnHideMessage').trigger( "click" );
    });

    it ("should remove the message when button is clicked.", function() {
      expect($('#pMsg')).toHaveText("");
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```